# Project Browser not updating with Package Deletion Script

Tags: enterprise-architect

The following method deletes a package.  The problem is that the Project Browser is never refreshed.  Calling Repository.RefreshModelView(0) forces the update, but it reopens the model and kills script execution.

Here is the method:

```
function clearPackage( pkg ) {
    var parent as EA.Package;
    parent = Repository.GetPackageByID(pkg.ParentID);

    var pkgList as EA.Collection;
    pkgList = parent.Packages;

    for (var i = 0; i < pkgList.Count; i++) {
        var p as EA.Package;
        p = pkgList.GetAt(i);

        if (p.PackageGUID == pkg.PackageGUID) {
            pkgList.Delete(i); 
            pkgList.Refresh();
            parent.Update();  // have tried with and without
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Inspecting pkgList.Count before and after pkgList.Refresh does show a change in size.  Again, the problem seems limited to the Project Browser.

Any ideas on how to refresh the Project Browser?

Cross posted on [Sparx Forums](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1414786623/0#0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a package you just need to delete the package itself. Sorry for the Perl, but thats my donkey :-)

```
my $p = $rep->GetTreeSelectedObject();
my $par = $rep->GetPackageByID ($p->ParentID);
my $idx = 0;
for my $sp (in $par->Packages) {
    if ($sp->PackageID == $p->PackageID) {
        $par->Packages->DeleteAt ($idx, 1);
        last;
    }
    $idx++;
}
$rep->RefreshModelView ($par->PackageID);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not really see the difference in the code (except only refreshing the parent), this still reloads the whole model if the package is hanging off the root package.  Also, DeleteAt does not appear to make a difference - the second parameter (refresh) is documented as not being implemented.

Comment: The 2nd parameter is mandatory (and not used - it's EA). Actually it's the same then as Delete :-/

Regarding the stop of the script execution at a Refresh(0) you should send a bug report. Does not seem ok. Since I ran my test script stand-alone I did not notice that in the first place.

Comment: P.S. In order to overcome the Refresh issue just postpone that with a flag to the end of the whole script (or do what Geert suggests). If you need to iterate through the cleaned list of sub-packages just load the object once again (use GetPackageByID or -GUID). I never use Refresh in any case. This is a most superfluous method.

Comment: Postponing is a great suggestion, but what I am trying to overcome is the "underlying model has changed" warning that pops up mid-script run.  For now, I am just clearing that error and the script continues.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer.  Both answers are equally appreciated (thank you very much for the effort) but neither exactly solves the problem.  All other things being equal, I am awarding to the user with less experience.

Comment: Finally resorted to renaming the package before deleting it.  This allows the creation of a package (with the same name as the original) without additional conflict.  The error has (temporarily?) disappeared, so I am not certain renaming the package is an ultimate solution, but it does appear to be working just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```cs
Repository.RefreshModelView(parent.PackageID);
```

That will refresh only the contents of the parent package, not the whole model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is somewhat of a moot point in my case.  I am deleting packages hanging off of the root model so and parent.PackageID is 0 anyway.

Comment: @Chris in that case there's no other option then to reload the whole model. You could consider using an executable or add-in to perform the task. That would avoid the issue of the scripts stopping when the model is reloaded

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  For now, I am just dealing with EA popping up an "underlying model changed" warning and continuing.